# Linter and Compiler Option for any to explicit type conversion without cast

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I would like to get an error in vscode and when compiling for the following scenarios:

scenario 1:

```
let myAny: any;
let myString: string;

myString = myAny;           // error
myString = <string> myAny;  // ok
myAny    = myString;        // error
myAny    = <any> myString;  // ok
```

scenario 2:

```
let myAny: any;
let myString: string;
foo(myParam: string): void{}

foo(myAny);                  // error
foo(myString);               // ok
foo(<string> myString);      // ok
```

Comment: Maybe https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unsafe-any/ ?

Comment: Since `any` is basically a way to turn off type checking, for easier compatibility with javascript, perhaps there is an alternative to using any?
Such as type union? `let typeAorB: A | B`
Or type intersection? `let typeAandB: A & B`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html